# Набегающие цифры при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите, в чем я ошибся.
Делаю как тут http://landing.romza.ru, но у меня цифры бегают по кругу, а не останавливаются, достигнув максимального значения((

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.p1').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos = topOfWindow+600) {
            $(this).animateNumber({ number: 10 });
        }
    });
});
```

**UPD:**

Вот такой скрипт работает правильно, но он стартует сразу при загрузке страницы.
Как сдлать чтобы он стартовал при прокрутке страницы до элемента?

```
$('.num').countTo({
        from: 0,
        speed: 100,
        refreshInterval: 1,
        formatter: function (value, options) {
            return value.toFixed(options.decimals);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Вы в условии не сравниваете значения, а переменной imagePos присваиваете новое значение!

Comment: А как же поправить?

Comment: Использовать вместо `=` двойное равно `==`.
Можете почитать: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Comment: Так вообще не работает. Заметил, что анимация набегает не по кругу, а как будто бы несколько раз. То есть добежала до 10 и потом снова с 0 до 10 и так раза 3-4.

Comment: Подрубил другой скрипт - но проблема другая - изложил в UPD к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('.p1').each(function(){
var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (imagePos = topOfWindow+600) {
        $(this).animateNumber({ number: 10 });
        $(this).stop();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Не работает. Вообще нет анимации.